# Use VPN through another machine?

Tags: networking, vpn

So, I've got two laptops: my work laptop, and my personal laptop.

My work laptop is extremely slow and painful to use, but my personal laptop is great . I would like to use my personal laptop to do my development, but the work laptop is the only machine that is allowed to connect to my company's VPN.

Is there any way to "tunnel" through my work laptop's VPN connection using my personal laptop? If not, what are some other viable options? I'd hate to have to resort to deploying every build onto my work laptop just to debug.

Comment: Oh my god I was going to ask a question 'word for word'. Great stuff. My with laptop has 'direct access' though so might have to do it using Ethernet between the two machines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's running Windows, you can use "Internet Connection Sharing" on your work laptop, if it has it, to share its VPN or other network connections with other computers on your local network.

If that fails, then there are many other more complicated solutions involving putting tunneling software on your work laptop.

Comment: One minor thing, you could just copy the VPN configuration over to the other laptop.  I've done this before and it worked great...  If you're going to break the rules (connecting your personal laptop to the network), doing it through the work laptop is just a formality.